# Is there any way to sync Facebook Comments and with comments on WordPress website?

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, functions

I want to sync all comments that are done on Facebook posts on the Facebook platform with comments done on my WordPress website. Suggestions for how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

for this purpose you need to use page builder, I cannot specify now but I am just telling you to use any page builder.
copy the embedded URL( must log in through Desktop)
when you click on the copy the embed code of a post then you can paste it in your page builder code or HTML section.

Add Facebook Comments to your Page
Facebook Comments are a simple way to put public comments onto your website.

according to Facebook help support and an article I go through [click here](https://answers.pagecloud.com/help/facebook)

Head to [Facebook for Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-comments/).
Enter the URL of the Facebook comment into the configurator.
Click "Get Code"
Copy embed code provided (after entering your website's information) using the CMD+C (on Mac) or CTRL+C (on Windows) shortcut.
Head to the PageCloud page you would like Facebook Comments to appear on.
Paste the embed code directly onto your page using CMD+V (on Mac) or CTRL+v (on Windows) Shortcut.
Click "Save" to save your changes to the page.
Click "View Live" to see the Facebook Comments on your page.

Add a Facebook Video to your Page
for understanding, you can go through this article [facebook embedding](https://answers.pagecloud.com/help/facebook)